# Regex getting part of the string after a word

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing a string and assigning each part of the string in a variable corresponding to their type:

**e.g.**

```
01:29:05 success login is successful : username
```

So I have to do this:

```
preg_match("/(1[012]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/", $str, $time);
echo $time[0];
```

Now I have the time. The next one is the `status` of the log.

```
preg_match("/success|failure|warning/", $str, $status);
echo $status[0];
```

The problem is the next `$message` and `$user`. The `$user` is optional, some logs do not have this. The `$message`, I only want to get the string after the `$status` and just before the colon `:`:

**My attempt to the message part**

```
preg_match(("/($status[0])+:*/"), $str, $message);
```

What could be the solution to this, or could there be more easier way.

**EDIT**

The desired output should look like:

```
array('
   'time'=> '01:29:05',
   'status'=> 'success',
   'message'=> 'login is successful',
   'user' => 'username'
')
```

Comment: What should the individual matches look like. Can you please include in your question?

Comment: okay, I added the desired output, to save it in the array is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I prepare the answer, one has been accepted. Anyway, I put it here.

```
preg_match("/(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?P<status>\w*) (?P<message>[^:]*) : (?P<user>.*)/", $str, $results)
```

#### Explanation

- results array will additionally to the position matches 1, 2, 3 and 4 contain the keys "time", "status", "message" and "user". The advantage is never having to think of the capture positions anymore when you modify the expression!

demo is here [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qS2hB1)

Comment: I guess this would really the best fit as for the question is concerned, considering the desired results I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

If your output is in the same format then Use [**`Preg_match_all`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

try with this regex pattern `([\d :]+)(\w+) ([a-zA-z ]+) : ([a-zA-z]+)` and you will get the first and second and third matches on the corresponding index of the output array

Do like this

```
$input_line="01:29:05 success login is successful : username";
preg_match("/([\d :]+)(\w+) ([a-zA-z ]+) : ([a-zA-z]+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/135758)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01:29:05 success login is successful : username
    [1] => 01:29:05 
    [2] => success
    [3] => login is successful 
    [4] => username
)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have not get the `$status`